# i am using ajax my with pagination on next page no. 2 my 'Edit' button and 'validation' not working

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

this picture is pagination and inspect values on edit button : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcLI.png)

1. my problem is that unable to edit value on next page in ajax, on first page edit button working,
2. and successfully edit validation not working after edit value.

on edit button values coming in json format i have only some knowledge of json and ajax

> My database table:

```
-----------------------------------
 sport_id   |     sport_name
-------------------------------------
     1         |      Volleyball
     2         |      Basketball
----------------------------------
table name is:- sports
```

my code is like that

```
controller
===========
    public function add_sport() {
            unset($_POST['gym_account_id']);
             if(isset($_POST['sport_id'])){ 
                 unset($_POST['sport_id']);
              $response = $this->queryData->sportAddData($_POST);
             }else{
              $sport_id = $_POST['sport_id'];
                    //  alert($sport_id);
                      $sport_name = array("sport_name" => $_POST['sport_name']);
                 $response = $this->queryData->sportEditData($sport_name,$sport_id);
             }             
              $this->Sports();
    }

model
========

         public function sportAddData($data) {
                $this->db->insert('sports', $data);
                $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
                return $insert_id;
            }

            public function sportEditData($sport_name,$sport_id) {
                    $this->db->where('sport_id', $sport_id);
                $this->db->update('sports', $sport_name);
            }

view
======
     <div class="page-title">
            <div class="title_left">
                &nbsp;
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert" style="display: <?php echo (!empty($_GET['success'])) ? 'block' : 'none'; ?>">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>Success!</strong> <?php echo $_GET['success']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="title_right">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search" style="text-align: right; margin-bottom: 26px; margin-right: -4px;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark create_sport1">Create</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark delete_items" >Delete</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark call_delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" style="display: none;" >Delete Athlete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

        <div class="row sport_form_block" id="add_sports" style="display: none;">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2 class="form_title1">Create New Sport</h2>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">
                        <br />
                        <form id="demo-form2" method="POST"  data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left sport_form">

                            <?php
                            $userType = $this->session->userData('userType');
                            $gymAccountId = $this->session->userData('gym_account_id');
                            if($userType == 1){
                            ?>

                            <?php }else{ ?>
                            <input type="hidden" name="gym_account_id" id="gym_account_id" value="<?php echo $gymAccountId; ?>" />
                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="sport_name">Sport Name <span class="required">*</span>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="sport_name" name="sport_name" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 edit_sportname">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">

                                     <input type="hidden" name="sport_id" value="" class="editsportid" id="editsportid" />
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary close_form" data-div="sport_form_block" type="button">Cancel</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary reset_sport_form" type="reset">Reset</button>
    <!--                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success submit_athlete1" data-url="<php echo base_url(); ?>athlete/add_athlete" data-table="<php echo base_url(); ?>athlete/get_athlete" data-form="athlete_form" data-div="athlete_form_block">Submit</button>-->
                                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success submit_athlete1" data-url="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/add_sport" data-table="<?php echo base_url(); ?>sport/get_athlete" data-form="sport_form" data-div="sport_form_block">Submit</button>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2>Sport(s)<small></small></h2>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="x_content">

                        <table id="sport-athlete-datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap bulk_action" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="no-sort" style="width: 30px;" ><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" class="flat check_all" data-check="athlete_list"></th>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Sport</th>
                                    <th class="no-sort" style="width: 50px;" >Edit</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach ($data['athletes'] as $key => $value) { ?>
                                    <tr>
    <!--                                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="<php echo $value['athlete_id']; ?>" class="flat athlete_list multiple_delete"></td>-->
                                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $value['sport_id']; ?>" class="flat athlete_list multiple_delete"></td>
                                         <td><?php echo $value['sport_id']; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $value['sport_name']; ?></td>
                                        <!--<td><a href="#/pencil-square-o" class="edit_athlete option_icon" data-json='<php echo json_encode($value, TRUE); ?>' data-block="athlete_form_block" data-form="athlete_form" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a></td>-->
                                   <td><button class="edit_sport option_icon" data-json='<?php echo $value['sport_id'] . ',' . $value['sport_name'] ?>' data-block="sport_form_block" data-form="sport_form" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
                                    </tr> 
                                <?php } ?>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

js
==
    $('.edit_sport').on('click', function (e) {
    //$('.edit_sport').on('click',  function (e) {
        $('#add_sports').slideDown();
        id = $(this).attr("data-json");
        var arr = id.split(',');
        $('.edit_sportname').val(arr[1]);
        $('.editsportid').val(arr[0]);
        alert(arr);
        console.log(arr);

          $('#function').val("update");
        $('.form_title1').html('Edit Sports');
        $('.' + $(this).data("block")).show();
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, "slow");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use onclick to bind event on button which will not apply for new element add to DOM via ajax call. You can use delegate or on to attach an events.

Comment: can give me a small example related to it

Comment: You can reference this article to see differences http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2010/08/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-function.html?m=1

Comment: sir, Vinh TRAN , i am unable to understand can u related to js according to my question